MATLAB is setting the max y value to 1 in plot, and scaling all of y
I am currently making a velocity vs time plotting app for an object that is falling with drag. I have worked out the function for it using a bit of calculus and am now trying to plot it. I have plotted it in demos with some values that I preprepared and gotten values od velocity much greater than 1 m/s (which is what I was expecting). However, when I tried to input the same values into my app, to plot them, on my plot the values never exceeded 1. This made me think that MATLAB is somehow scaling my y axis to make all the values plot relative to 1 (which is seemingly the equivalent of the terminal velocity). I tried using,
ylim([0 n]);

to fix this, but that didnt change anything. Here is my code:
function startupFcn(app)
            app.MaxMassEditField.Value = 100;
            app.AreaEditField.Value = 1;
            app.DragCoefficientEditField.Value = 1;
            app.gEditField.Value = 1;
            app.MediumDensitryEditField.Value = 1;
            app.MassSlider.Limits = [10^(-7), app.MaxMassEditField.Value];

            Area = app.AreaEditField.Value;
            Cd = app.DragCoefficientEditField.Value;
            g = app.gEditField.Value;
            density = app.MediumDensitryEditField.Value;
            mass = app.MassSlider.Value;


            
            time = linspace(0, 100, 10000);
            exponent = exp(2*sqrt((g*Area*density*Cd)/(2*mass))*time);
            coefficeint = -sqrt((2*mass*g)/(density*Area*Cd));
            velocity = coefficeint * (1-exponent)./(1+exponent);
            plot(app.UIAxes, time, velocity)
            ylim([0 100]);
        end

(^for startup function)
Area = app.AreaEditField.Value;
            Cd = app.DragCoefficientEditField.Value;
            g = app.gEditField.Value;
            density = app.MediumDensitryEditField.Value;
            mass = app.MassSlider.Value;

            app.MassSlider.Limits = [10^(-7), app.MaxMassEditField.Value];

            
            time = linspace(0, 100, 1000);
            exponent = exp(2*sqrt((g*Area*density*Cd)/(2*mass))*time);
            velocity = - (1-exponent)./(1+exponent);
            plot(app.UIAxes, time, velocity);
            ylim([0 8]);

(^for every time the "plot" button is pressed)
I am super lost right now. Thank you in advance for your help.

If the effect you are describing is not strictly related to the app, you will find more help by providing a version of this code that runs in a script, with numerical values filled. Hve you tried printin velocity to asses that indeed, the values are higher, and its a plotting issue? because my guess would be tht the math is wrong, or the values are not being input properly, instead.

You probably need to specify axes for ylim, ylim(app.UIAxes, [0 n]).
